# Как реализовать отправку нескольких постов в одном письме Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

На сайте есть возможность подписки на новости. Ежедневно публикуется 10-15 новостей и каждую новость отправлять подписчикам как то не очень идея. Хотелось бы отправлять одно письмо ежедневно в одно и тоже время, но уже в нем будут все новости за день.

Как на ларке можно такое реализовать? Я знаю что есть планировщик, где ставишь задачу и он её выполняет, проблема именно в том, как вот эти новостные посты за день в одну пачку собрать за определенный период, например все посты с пн 10:00 по вт 10:00 и отправить их письмом подписчику?

Comment: Делаете выборку из БД и передаете отправщику писем, вроде так как-то ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаете команду https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#generating-commands
2. В ней делаете нужную выборку пользователей и новостей с помощью Laravel Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent
3. Отправляете письмо: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail